# Proper usage of Mockito.verify

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm new to unit testing and i had a simple question regarding the usage of `verify` method used in Mockito. here's the class i used for testing.

```
public class Foo{
int n = 0;
void addFoo(String a){
    if(a == "a")
    add(1);
}

protected void add(int num){
    n =1;
}

public int get(){
    return n;
}
```

}

And here's my Unit test.

```
public class FooTest {
@Mock Foo f;

@Test
public void test() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    f.addFoo("a");

    //Passes
    Mockito.verify(f).addFoo("a");

    //Fails
    Mockito.verify(f).add(1);
}
```

}

And i get a

```
   Wanted but not invoked:
f.add(1);
-> at FooTest.test(FooTest.java:22)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at FooTest.test(FooTest.java:16)
```

exception.

How do you verify that `add(int num)` is called ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the point of `verify`. 
In your test, `Foo f` is a **mock object** - `Foo`'s internal implementation is ignored, and only the behavior you recorded on it (using `when(f.someMethod().thenXXX`) would happen.

The point of mocking and verifying is to test interactions while ignoring the internal implementation.
In this example, you would probably have another class that **uses** `Foo`, and you'd want to test whether it invokes the correct methods of the given `Foo` instance.

Quick example:

Assume you have a class the uses the `Foo` class you presented in your question:

```
public class FooUser {
    private Foo f;

    public void setFoo(Foo f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return f;
    }

    public void addToFoo(String string) {
        f.add(string);
    }
}
```

Now, you'd want to test that `FooUser#addToFoo(String)` indeed invokes the correct `add(String)` method of `Foo`:

```
@RunWith (MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooUserTest {
    @Mock Foo f;
    FooUser fUser;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        fUser = new FooUser();
        fUser.setFoo(f);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fUser.addToFoo("a");
        Mockito.verify(f).addFoo("a");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think i get it now. Is there any way to know if the proper methods are being called in the class that i'm testing ?

Comment: Do you mean is there a way to know if `mockA.methodA` really invokes `mockA.methodB`? You could try using spied objects instead of mocked objects, but IMHO it's more trouble than its worth. If you want to test `methodB`, test `methodB`s public contract, don't just verify that it calls or doesn't call another internal method.